# Blender monkeys ears are missing after import

Tags: three.js

I tried to import the famous Blender (2.69) monkey, but the ears are missing. I didn't do anything special, neither in Blender nor in Three.js.

I just added a material with a red colour and imported it via the official Blender to Three.js exporter. Double-siding the material doesn't help either.

[image: Blender]

[image: Three.js]

Comment: Can you publish both the blend and json file?? It makes it easier for problem solving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet the camera's `far` value is not high enough...